# How do I change the labels of a dendogram using the fviz_dend function from the "factoextra" package in R?

Tags: r, graphics, shiny, dendrogram

I am creating a shiny app that showcases different clustering techniques such as hierarchical and k-means clustering using a cereal dataset as an example. I am using the fviz_dend function from the "factoextra" package to create my dendogram. However, when I do this the dendogram does not show the names of the cereals as the labels, rather it shows the numerical representation instead. Is there a way to change the numerical values to labels? I am attaching below a picture of my current dendogram using the fviz_dend function and a picture of a dendogram I made using the plot function in base R. Note that the dendogram in created by the plot function has the labels of the cereals as I need them (what I am trying to achieve).

Dendogram Created Using fviz_dend:

[image: Dendogram I want to modify]

```
### Code for dendogram using fvizdend
hc <- hclust(dist(scale(xv), method = input$dmeth), method = input$meth)

fviz_dend(hc, k = input$clustgroup, cex = 0.5, k_colors = c("#2E9FDF", "#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
                color_labels_by_k = T, rect = T, show_labels = T)
```

Dendogram Created Using plot function:

[image]

```
hc <- hclust(dist(scale(xv), method = input$dmeth), method = input$meth)
plot(hc, labels = xv$Brand)
```

Comment: You might wish top look at the dendextend package to get more refined control over your dendrogram display. See here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the `row.names` of `xv` with the labels?

```
rownames(xv) <-  xv$Brand
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the above solution worked for me but first I had to use xv<-as.data.frame(xv) as for some reason my data frame was considered a tribble.

Answer (score 0):

Change the labels of the hclust object(hc in your case) and then plot the dendrogram.

```
    hc$labels <- xv$Brand

    library("factoextra")
    fviz_dend(hc, cex = 0.5)
```